# MySql "Column 'quantity' cannot be null" even when value is included

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting the error: 'Column 'quantity' cannot be null', when the value is included in my insert statement (it works when the value is not included)

```
INSERT INTO orders (time_submitted, time_updated, account, currency, price, quantity)
VALUES (
  '2019-05-13 16:32:36',
  '2019-05-13 16:32:36',
  '1',
  'USD',
  '100',
  '5'
)
```

Create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE "orders" (
 "order_id" int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 "time_submitted" text,
 "time_updated" text,
 "account" double DEFAULT NULL,
 "currency" text,
 "price" decimal(19,7) DEFAULT NULL,
 "quantity" decimal(19,7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000000',
 PRIMARY KEY ("order_id")
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1167 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

MySql v 5.7.22

Comment: Are you sure it's that statement generating the error? For what it's worth, I [can't reproduce that error](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff111a/1). You're using double quotes which require [`ANSI_QUOTES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) to be enabled. You're also using `TEXT` very liberally when `VARCHAR(255)` or `DATETIME` is more appropriate.

Comment: Yes, this statement is being run directly in MySql workbench.

Comment: Your code runs fine:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b00fd26256a384db94bab1ddf54de65c.  You may have a trigger that is causing the problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff 13:17:12    select trigger_schema, trigger_name, action_statement from information_schema.triggers    0 row(s) returned    0.016 sec / 0.000 sec

Comment: I've boiled it down to INSERT INTO orders (quantity) VALUES (16.500) and I still get the same error...

Comment: It's possible you have STRICT_ALL_TABLES or  STRICT_TRANS_TABLES in your sql_mode variable. More info here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict

Comment: @raphael75 Yes, I have STRICT_TRANS_TABLES...